# P4 Perforce Undelete or Recreate Deleted Changelist

Tags: perforce

I accidentally deleted the wrong change list.  I need to either undelete it, or create a new one that is identical to the deleted one.

Can somebody suggest a process to accomplish either goal?  TIA!

Answer (score 2):

You may need to expand on what you mean by "deleted a changelist" -- a changelist can only be deleted if it is empty.  So to recreate a deleted changelist, all you need to do is create a new empty changelist:

```
p4 change
```

Changelist descriptions aren't stored in the spec depot IIRC so unfortunately there's not an easy way to recover the old description, but usually changelist descriptions aren't super important so I'd assume it's okay to just type up a new one?  (If it is super important you could get it from the journal but that's challenging enough that I won't go into it here.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

By deleted, I mean that I executed a p4 change -d change_number command.

I need to create a new change list that contains the files that were in the change list I deleted, with the versions specified, in order to be able to specify that set of changes for integration into another branch.

Is it possible to create a new change list, then simply add the Files section with those files, postfixed by the #version_number?  It doesn't matter if the change list number changes, so long as I have a changelist with those contents.  Thanks!

Comment: Further detail: I had submitted this changelist before accidentally deleting it while trying to clean up enough to delete the client.

Comment: p4 change -d will not delete a changelist with files in it, nor will it delete a submitted changelist (unless you do other stuff first and use a special flag).  I am *very* confident of this since I've written a lot of tooling around it.  Is this a thing that actually happened or are you describing a hypothetical?  :)

Comment: Used no special flags, though of course I was detaching "fixes" in order to allow the change list to be deleted, then deleting multiple change lists in order to be able to delete the client.  In the process I accidentally deleted the submitted change list.  This is a real case, and the change list was logged as having been deleted in a tracking system, but it sounds like from your reply that this may be a misstatement of some kind and that the delete command completed successfully, but didn't actually do anything. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: You could always try "p4 describe CHANGE" to see.  What "tracking system" was this and where does it get its data from?

Comment: The scripting capability of Perforce is used to send notifications to the bug tracking system when P4 submits and certain change list modifications occur.  I'm guessing at this point that the p4 change -d number command I issued on the command line, the one that issued no error or warning, but (if I understand you correctly) actually did nothing but did, however, trigger an event that caused the script to connect to the tracking system and log the change list as deleted.

Comment: If the trigger is on form-delete, it fires before the delete succeeds, so you could get a false positive that way.  If you got no error from the change -d command, though, I'm actually pretty sure that the changelist was indeed just an empty pending changelist (not a submitted changelist).